# Partial xslt transformation on the xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

My sample xml :

```
<root> 
 <changeTag value="true"/>
 <a_original> name ="foo"</a_original>
 <b_original> name ="foo1"</b_original>

 <changeTag value = "false"/>
 <a_original> name ="foo1"</a_original>
 <b_original> name ="foo1"</b_original>
</root>
```

I want a transformation in xslt which would convert the nodes which are after 'changeTag value = "true" ' but not after ' changeTag value = "false" '. **I want all the nodes which are between changeValue value = " true "  and changeValue value = " false " to be same as input xml** and perform all the transformations after changeValue value = " false "

My sample XML output(Expected)

```
<root> 
 <changeTag value="true"/>
 <a_original> name ="foo"</a_original>
 <b_original> name ="foo1"</b_original>

 <changeTag value = "false"/>
 <a_changed> name ="foo1"</a_changed>
 <b_changed> name ="foo1"</b_changed>
</root>
```

XSLT to change the 'a_original'

```
<xsl:template match = "a_original">
<a_changed>
<xsl:apply-templates select ="@* | node()">
</a_changed>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match = "b_original[@name='foo1']">
<b_changed>
<xsl:apply-templates select ="@* | node()">
</b_changed>
</xsl:template>
```

Need a solution for XSLT 1.0. There are a lot of different operations happening such as deletion and addition of attributes, deletion and addition of tags etc in my actual XSLT file, **so its preferable if i can give a condition which mentions when to skip the nodes rather than the condition which mentions when to change.**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your XML was well-formed. (i.e it was `<a_original name="foo"></a_original>` and not `<a_original> name ="foo"</a_original>` then the template match you want is

```
<xsl:template match="a_original[preceding-sibling::changeTag[1]/@value='false']">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="a_original[preceding-sibling::changeTag[1]/@value='false']">
        <a_changed>
            <xsl:apply-templates select ="@* | node()" />
        </a_changed>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want a more generic template, try something like this....

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(self::changeTag)][preceding-sibling::changeTag[1]/@value='false']">
    <xsl:element name="{substring-before(local-name(), '_original')}_changed">
        <xsl:apply-templates select ="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

This will rename any such element from `_original` to `_changed`. If your actual XML elements are not actually suffixed with `_original` you may need to explain precisely what the rules are for renaming.

EDIT: If you can't come up with a generic rule for renaming, you might have to do something like this instead...

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(self::changeTag)][preceding-sibling::changeTag[1]/@value='false']">
    <xsl:variable name="newName">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="self::a_original">a_changed</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="self::b_original[@name='foo1']">b_changed</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$newName}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select ="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Ok, but i don't want to write it this way. I have a lot of transformations that needs to happen and putting all of them under this match condition won't do. What i want is to write a match condition which would skip the nodes between the two changeValue tags rather than something which would perform operations on the ones which are after that

Comment: I have extended my answer with a more generic template.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your input. I have updated the question. As mentioned there isn't any standard transformation pattern, as far as i can see there are 20-30 different types of them. That's why i am not very keen on adding them inside a bigger match condition.

Comment: I've extended my answer with another suggestion.

Comment: Ok, sorry for being so persistent about it but is it possible to not change the structure of my previous transformations. Its not just renaming but there are a various different types of operations that are happening as well, such as addition of attributes, deletion of attributes so on and so forth. My xslt code is already 1000 lines + and changing each of them to incorporate the outer match condition is not very optimum.

Comment: I have edited the question, i hope it makes sense now.